# How to test react app with Jenkins Blue Ocean?

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, github, npm, continuous-integration

## Created a react app with `create-react-app`

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app-3
```

## Just added one file named `Jenkinsfile` in it

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node('master') {
    try {
        stage('build') {
            sh "npm install"
        }

        stage('test') {
            sh "npm test"
        }
    } catch(error) {
        throw error
    } finally {

    }
}
```

## Push it to Github and add new pipeline from Jenkins Blue Ocean

Jenkins Blue Ocean found github repo which created above. Checked it.

## Then it ran automatically

Got error when ran `npm test`

```
[my-app-3_master-AOH6VCAOPUS4BCUQLNULA3ABCOUVZZEDO2LPJHNW3MX7M2F4KQIA] Running shell script

+ npm test

npm ERR! path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-app-3_master-AOH6VCAOPUS4BCUQLNULA3ABCOUVZZEDO2LPJHNW3MX7M2F4KQIA/package.json

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-app-3_master-AOH6VCAOPUS4BCUQLNULA3ABCOUVZZEDO2LPJHNW3MX7M2F4KQIA/package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent 



npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2018-05-16T08_57_26_292Z-debug.log

script returned exit code 254
```

/var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2018-05-16T08_57_26_292Z-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'test' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.1
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-app-3_master-AOH6VCAOPUS4BCUQLNULA3ABCOUVZZEDO2LPJHNW3MX7M2F4KQIA/package.json'
5 verbose cwd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-app-3_master-AOH6VCAOPUS4BCUQLNULA3ABCOUVZZEDO2LPJHNW3MX7M2F4KQIA
6 verbose Linux 4.4.0-1052-aws
7 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "test"
8 verbose node v8.11.1
9 verbose npm  v5.6.0
10 error path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-app-3_master-AOH6VCAOPUS4BCUQLNULA3ABCOUVZZEDO2LPJHNW3MX7M2F4KQIA/package.json
11 error code ENOENT
12 error errno -2
13 error syscall open
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-app-3_master-AOH6VCAOPUS4BCUQLNULA3ABCOUVZZEDO2LPJHNW3MX7M2F4KQIA/package.json'
15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

I checked this path: `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-app-3_master-AOH6VCAOPUS4BCUQLNULA3ABCOUVZZEDO2LPJHNW3MX7M2F4KQIA/`, only exist `package-lock.json` but without other files. So it can't find them. Why didn't pull the full files?